# Posts not accessible on a local copy of production Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am in the process of replicating a production WordPress website on a local system. While I am able to access the home page, the posts and any other links are not accessible and I get an error

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

This local WordPress has been set up on:

1. Apache 2.4
2. PHP 5.6

Copy of .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so has been enabled.

Let me know if any details are needed.

Comment: Have you changed the Wordpress setup to match the local virtual host you've set up? Because the transferred domain is probably not setup on your host?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie: I am working on a Windows system. I took a complete back up of the WordPress db and in the back up SQL file, I replaced all instances of the production host name with "localhost". Do I have to do any other changes? Thanks!

Comment: Eh... have you set up a virtual host and modified your hosts-file so you can type something like "testsite.loc" in the browser and go to your site? If not, you have not set up a proper test-environment. Set up a virtual host, make sure the hosts file match, and so on. And then, replace localhost with your selected test-domain.

Comment: are you using any virtual host? or simply accessing site as `http://localhost/my_site`?

Answer (score 0):

Create virtual host. Use same domain name and make entry in hosts file(/etc/hosts). Thats all to run wordpress on local.